# Can't download artefacts from my nexus server

Tags: maven, nexus

I have setup a nexus server in our intranet with https and an apache proxy. The nexus UI works fine. But when I test it on my local machine with a mvn command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DgroupId=nl.iteye -DartifactId=App1
```

I get this error

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/myuser/.m2/repository), nexus (https://machine.domain.org/nexus/content/groups/public/)] -> [Help 1]
```

With these warnings

```
Downloading: https://machine.domain.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.3/maven-clean-plugin-2.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.3
Downloading: https://machine.domain.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3/maven-install-plugin-2.3.pom
```

That's my local settings for maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>https://machine.domain.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

I saw this in the nexus logs

```
jvm 1    | 2014-05-22 15:43:53,687+0200 INFO  [qtp1476181708-44] admin org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://repo1.maven.org:80: The target server failed to respond
```

I tries a view things but didn't succeed. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have a firewall, you may have to configure a proxy in your settings.xml file

Comment: there is a firewall but port 80/443 is open, but you mean on the server machine the settings.xml for maven?

Comment: No, when you need a proxy on your development machine to reach the web, you need to configure it also in your settings.xml . This doesn't seem to be your case, though